# Starting Hudson server

Tags: java, hudson

Is there an way of starting the hudson server with just the .jar files in .hudson\war\WEB-INF\lib\ ??
Is it necessary to extract it from the hudson.war file??
I am using windows and I don't want it to start as a service..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to extract the war file. You start hudson like this:

```
java -jar hudson.war
```

If you need to pass it command line arguments, you can do something like this:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar hudson.war --httpPort=8090 --prefix=/hudson --logfile=/tmp/hudson.log"
```

Comment: thanx for ur info but I tried to mean a bit different though I agree I wasn't very clear..can u plz refer to what I wrote to nos??

Comment: @Arnab, why do you not want to distribute the war file? It's packaged as a war for a reason. That's the way you need to start it. If you could expand on the reasoning behind your desire to just use the jar there might be another solution.

Comment: @Irm -- size is an issue. if I distribute the war file, it will take the disk space and when the user starts hudson again the home directory will be created and again the same amount of space will be duplicated..So i want that if we can start with any of the jar files in lib then we won't need the war file at all!!

Comment: @Arnab, I don't think this is possible. Just give them the war file.

Comment: @Irm, ya I guess so..no other option..thnx nyways :-)

Answer (score 4):

To start hudson, just run:

```
java -jar hudson.war
```

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Starting+and+Accessing+Hudson

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear..sorry for that..but actually even I start it that way but what I wanted to know is if I give someone the lib of .jar files , will he be able to start hudson with something like java -jar hudson-core-xxxx.jar??